# Asynchronous retry method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, rags-to-riches

I've written an asynchronous retry method as an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462525/parallel-foreach-using-thread-sleep-equivalent). I'd like to get your opinion of the implementation and whether there are better ways to implement this. You could also implement this with `async-await` but I thought this would be a more efficient implementation.

```
public static Task RetryAsync(Func<bool> retryFunc, CancellationToken cancellationToken, int retryInterval)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    var timer = new Timer((state) =>
    {
        var taskCompletionSource = (TaskCompletionSource<object>)state;

        if (!taskCompletionSource.Task.IsCompleted)
        {
            try
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    taskCompletionSource.SetException(new TaskCanceledException("RetryAsync cancelled"));
                }
                else if (retryFunc())
                {
                    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                taskCompletionSource.SetException(ex);
            }
        }

    }, tcs, 0, retryInterval);


    //// Once the task is complete, dispose of the timer so it doesn't keep firing.
    tcs.Task.ContinueWith(t => timer.Dispose(),
                          CancellationToken.None,
                          TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                          TaskScheduler.Default);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to [codereview.se]! Unknowingly you became the second contestant in our new CR-Game. For more information see [tag:rags-to-riches]. Feel free to drop by in [chat] or on [meta] ;)

Comment: Please see this meta post. [Is it okay to update my questions for an iterative review?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c). TL;DR: We prefer you ask a new follow up question if you wish to have revised code reviewed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You could also implement this with `async-await` but I thought this would be a more efficient implementation.

1. When performance matters, don't guess, *measure*. When it doesn't matter (which is 97 % of the time [according to some](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)), write code that is readable and maintainable.
2. Why do you think small increase in efficiency (most likely less than 1 ms) would matter here, when the retry interval is probably going to be hundreds of milliseconds or more (and [can't effectively be less than 15 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744104/41071))?

---

```
Func<bool> retryFunc
```

Consider adding another overload that allows you to retry async functions (i.e. `Func<Task<bool>> retryFunc`).

---

```
CancellationToken cancellationToken
```

It might make sense to make this an optional parameter, some users might not need cancellation.

---

```
int retryInterval
```

I think it would be better to use `TimeSpan` here, that way both your code and the code of your users becomes more clear. If you want to keep using `int`, document very clearly the unit used, possibly by even renaming the parameter to something like `retryIntervalMs`.

You don't want to be the next [Mars Climate Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter).

---

When the `CancellationToken` is canceled, why do you wait for the timer tick to cancel the returned `Task`? You could use [`Register()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321635) to make sure the `Task` is canceled as soon as the `CancellationToken` is.

---

```
if (!taskCompletionSource.Task.IsCompleted)
```

What's the purpose of this check? If it's because you're worried that `retryFunc` might run longer than `retryInterval`, then I think your logic is flawed. When I have an operation that takes 1 minute to run and I ask for retry after 5 seconds, I probably don't want to have 12 instances of the operation running at the same time.

You could achieve this by using [`Change()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Timer.Change).

And even when you want this behavior, you should probably also switch to using `TrySet` versions of the `TaskCompletionSource` methods, to avoid unnecessary exceptions.

---

```
if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    taskCompletionSource.SetException(new TaskCanceledException("RetryAsync cancelled"));
}
```

This way, the `Task` will be in the `Faulted` state. To get it to the correct `Canceled` state, use `SetCanceled()`.

---

```
//// Once the task is complete, dispose of the timer so it doesn't keep firing.
tcs.Task.ContinueWith(t => timer.Dispose(),
                      CancellationToken.None,
                      TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                      TaskScheduler.Default);
```

This closure is important also because it keeps the `Timer` rooted, so it prevents it from being GCed prematurely. I would expand the comment to explain that.

(Also, why are you using four slashes for a comment? Two are enough.)

Answer (score 0):

The suggested approach needs a timeout implementation and moreover, it has issues of calling the same function again if it is not already completed, due to the retry of timer mechanism.